# Can I set FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS only for status bar?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-statusbar

I need to make transparent status bar. I am using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)` and it is make status bar as I want. But it also affect navigation bar: it became transparent and `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.BLACK)` do nothing.

Is there way to make transparent status bar only and not navigation bar?

Comment: Can you please post image of your current and expected behavior?

Answer (score 38):

this work for me

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
)
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="TranslucentStatusBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

v21\styles.xml

```
<style name="TranslucentStatusBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

status bar will be transparent or translucent, **navigation bar won't**

hope this helps!

Comment: prevent scroll view from scrolling

Comment: That doesn't work on Samsung SM-T295 (Android 10, One UI 2.1). The navigation bar appears on top of the content.

Comment: This does not work! I can't set light theme on the navigation bar. Only white buttons with black translucent background.

Answer (score 21):

using [mikepenz's comment](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/254#issuecomment-95685807)

what I exactly working code (converted to kotlin) below here.

```
// at AppCompatActivity, min SDK is 16, I tested api 25
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

Comment: window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
Is better (I needed this to keep status bar icons black instead of white)

Answer (score 16):

> Scroll down to check how the end result looks like

First of all, define your styles.xml something like this-

> styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**DO NOT** add the following line

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

Adding above line will NOT shift the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown on a Dialog with an `EditText`

Then override this style in v21 **and** v23 styles like this-

> v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

> v23/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

Activity code - Kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(
            LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_RESOURCE_ID)
    .
    .
.
}
```

Activity code - Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_RESOURCE_ID)
    .
    .
    .
}
```

End result
[image: End result]

Comment: Almost device is work well but It isn't work on Samsung Note 10+ running Android 10 and One UI 2.0 The navigation bar still transparent and overlap app's content.

Comment: FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS hide actionbar

Answer (score 11):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
fun showTransparentStatusbar() {
        activity!!.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }


    fun removeStatusbarFlags() {
        activity!!.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
```

Comment: it makes the status bar disappear

Answer (score 4):

Try this and wont regret it

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this 
to hide status bar and navigation bar

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attributes.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attributes);
```

and for showing the navigationBar again use this

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

    }
```

the color is grey for me, maybe you can force it to your primary color

Answer (score 3):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Just flag above worked for me. Navigation buttons are visible, status bar and action bar are hidden.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Is not working. Test device nexus 5.

Comment: That was 3 years ago )
Yep. WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN worked for nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution bro

```
<style name="transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">//AppCompat is the key; You can choose any other theme than the light-theme, but stick to AppCompat
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    //Other styling(optional)
</style>
```

and then apply this transparent theme to your activity manifest like this

```
 <activity
      ...
      android:theme="@style/transparent"/>
```

Comment: which Android are you using because its for older android 6 or 7

Answer (score 1):

For all those interested in workarounds/hacks because Android API concerning this matter is just awful. Do not use any system window flags, set negative margin to the root of your layout, and then use `setStatusBarColor` to make your `StatusBar` transparent.

```
statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_24dp);
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId != 0) {
    statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}

FrameLayout.LayoutParams rootParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) binding.getRoot().getLayoutParams();
rootParams.topMargin = -statusBarHeight;
binding.getRoot().setLayoutParams(rootParams);

getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```

where binding.getRoot() is of course the root of your layout

and result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes , You can use this code in Style.xml

```
<style name="transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">//AppCompat is the key; You can choose any other theme than the light-theme, but stick to AppCompat

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00000000</item>//THIS is the important part.
    //Other styling(optional)
</style>
```

Then to apply it to your layout, simply add the following line in the root layout(view):

```
android:theme="@style/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
)

<style name="TranslucentStatusBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works on Samsung S10+ (Pie), Oppo F7 and Oppo F5S (Oreos):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

As asked by the original poster, the app area is expanded on top and covers the status bar (where the clock is).  But the android navigation (virtual) buttons remains at the bottom of the screen and the app sits on top of the android buttons.

Comment: It doesn't make the status bar transparent. It simply hides the status bar.