# Android Studio - How to have a transparent status bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar

**Description:**

This is a question that had been made on this site but answers were not helpful for me. I need to make ONLY the status bar transparent and this is what i found:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

I´ve tried it and it works but it makes transparent the bottom action bar too (With bottom baction bar i mean this:)

[image]

**How can i do to make ONLY the top status bar transparent?**

**Thanks so much for reading**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194303/11546258) on this post, as it seems like it is exactly what you are looking for.

Would hate to type it all here again but the answer from @Yunus might not work if all conditions are not met, mainly what the documentation for statusBarColor tells you.

> The color for the status bar. If the color is not opaque, consider setting {@link android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE} and {@link android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN}. For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with {@link android.R.attr#windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds} and the status bar must not have been requested to be translucent with {@link android.R.attr#windowTranslucentStatus}. Corresponds to {@link android.view.Window#setStatusBarColor(int)}.

Refer the answer for setting those required flags and style, also to keep navigation bar simply DO NOT add `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` flag in case you have it in some code.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom theme that sets the status bar color. It works on version 21 and up:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
         <!-- You can customize it by changing statusBarColor. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/pieces_cherry</item>
</style>
```

And in your manifest you need to set this as your app theme

Comment: Thanks for answering but @color/pieces_cherry doesn´t exists. I don´t want to change status bar color. I want to make it transparent..

Comment: @TomasM Here a color what you want `@android:color/transparent`