# set FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS but scroll not working in android

Tags: android

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzgSU.png) Base Activity Code.

```
 window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
 window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
```

- Hide navigation bar and Transparent status bar is working fine
- Full screen successfully but here scroll is not working please help.

Comment: +1, also not solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347297/can-i-set-flag-layout-no-limits-only-for-status-bar#comment111738084_52092975

Comment: Finally I have found 3 lines code solution to have just status bar transparent and scrolling working. To have both status bar and navigation bar transparent + scrolling working solution takes more lines. I will publish it soon here.